# CB Radio in Namibia - is a license needed? If yes, what is the situation in practice?

Tags: legal, communication, namibia

It is my understanding that in Namibia, a license is required to use a CB radio (our use case is quite typical, a two-car journey across the country), as described on this website: http://www.qsl.net/oh2mcn/v51.htm. Is this information (and my understanding of it) correct? If so, are these procedures followed and enforced in practice, or is it a "dead" law?

Comment: The web page you linked only talks about obtaining a _ham radio_ license. I saw nothing there about "CB" radio, or any other similar radio service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official licensing authority in Namibia is the [Communications Regulatory Authority of Namibia](http://www.cran.na/). The The Namibian Comunications Commission appears to have been replaced in [2009](http://www.4x4community.co.za/forum/showthread.php/85572-New-Comms-ACT-No-more-CB-VHF-29-guest-licenses).

The CRAN web site is awful and I can't find anything on it. Instead, I searched for sites linking or mentioning cran.na and found the [Namibian Amateur Radio Centre](http://www.nam-arc.org/index.php/en/home-en/licencing/guest-licence) saying:

> **Guest Licences for Radio Amateurs visiting Namibia**
>
> In Namibia, there is only one application form which applies for all
>   kinds of spectrum users (from Commercial Broadcasting Service up to
>   **Citizen Band Service**). This may seem unusual, but has been officially
>   implemented by CRAN and thus has to be used also when applying for a
>   guest licence.

The site provides a link with an [application form](http://www.nam-arc.org/files/cran/Spectrum-Use-Licence.pdf).

You must attach **a copy of your home licence** and pay 60N$ (approx USD$4)

> The cheapest way of paying your guest licence is in cash after your
>   arrival in Namibia at the office of CRAN. Then your licence will be
>   handed out directly to you. CRAN can send the licence to your contact
>   person's P.O.Box in Namibia if you pay in advance via the expensive
>   electronic banking or via your local contact person. The issued guest
>   licence is valid for the complete calendar year.

I would recommend that you attempt to [contact](http://www.nam-arc.org/index.php/en/contact-us) the site owners if you require further information.